# Partition by and invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

Please see the code below:

```
SELECT
mp_asin.CATEGORY_CODE AS Category_id 
,mp_asin.SUBCATEGORY_CODE AS SUBCATEGORY
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME 
,mp_asin.COLOR_NAME AS Color_Name 
,mp_asin.PRODUCT_SITE_LAUNCH_DAY AS PSLD 
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME as TEEN 
,mp_asin.BRAND_CODE AS Brand_Code 
,mp_asin.REPLENISHMENT_CODE as REPLEN_CODE 
,mp_asin.REPLENISHMENT_CATEGORY_ID AS Replen_TIER
,mp_asin.ASIN as ASIN
,MIN(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME)) as MIN_TEEN_RC
,MAX(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME)) as MAX_TEEN_RC

FROM
d_mp_asins mp_asin

WHERE

MIN_TEEN_RC <> MAX_TEEN_RC
AND mp_asin.CATEGORY_CODE =('30905500') 
AND mp_asin.SUBCATEGORY_CODE =('30905560')
AND mp_asin.REGION_ID = 1
AND mp_asin.MARKETPLACE_ID = 1
AND mp_asin.GL_PRODUCT_GROUP = 309
```

My error seems to be in the `Where` clause. Is there another way to write

```
Min_Teen_RC <> MAX_TEEN_RC
```

I tried the following and got the same error:

```
MIN(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME)) <> MAX(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME))
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> ORA-00904: "MAX_TEEN_RC": invalid identifier

Thanks for your help!

Here is the entire code for V2:

```
SELECT
mp_asin.CATEGORY_CODE AS Category_id 
,mp_asin.SUBCATEGORY_CODE AS SUBCATEGORY
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME 
,mp_asin.COLOR_NAME AS Color_Name 
,mp_asin.PRODUCT_SITE_LAUNCH_DAY AS PSLD 
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME as TEEN 
,mp_asin.BRAND_CODE AS Brand_Code 
,mp_asin.REPLENISHMENT_CODE as REPLEN_CODE 
,mp_asin.REPLENISHMENT_CATEGORY_ID AS Replen_TIER
,mp_asin.ASIN as ASIN
,MIN(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME)) as MIN_TEEN_RC
,MAX(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME)) as MAX_TEEN_RC

FROM
d_mp_asins mp_asin

WHERE

MIN(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME)) <> MAX(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME))
AND mp_asin.CATEGORY_CODE =('30905500') 
AND mp_asin.SUBCATEGORY_CODE =('30905560')
AND mp_asin.REGION_ID = 1
AND mp_asin.MARKETPLACE_ID = 1
AND mp_asin.GL_PRODUCT_GROUP = 309

Group by
mp_asin.CATEGORY_CODE
,mp_asin.SUBCATEGORY_CODE 
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME
,mp_asin.COLOR_NAME
,mp_asin.PRODUCT_SITE_LAUNCH_DAY
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME
,mp_asin.BRAND_CODE
,mp_asin.REPLENISHMENT_CODE
,mp_asin.REPLENISHMENT_CATEGORY_ID
,mp_asin.ASIN
```

Comment: Thanks MAT, the error on the 2nd time was the following:  Statement 1 is not valid. ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Comment: You're also still referring to `mp.` for a few columns; as in your previous question you need to use your table alias consistently...

Comment: Um, why are you concatenating `PARENT_ASIN_NAME` and `COLOR_NAME`?  Doing so would only slow down the `PARTITION BY` (because now it **can't** use an index).  Do you really need that `GROUP BY`?  If you do have duplicate rows, I'd prefer using `DISTINCT` instead.  Note that combining `GROUP BY` and `PARTITION BY` can result in... non-intuitive results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT
mp_asin.CATEGORY_CODE AS Category_id 
,mp_asin.SUBCATEGORY_CODE AS SUBCATEGORY
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME 
,mp_asin.COLOR_NAME AS Color_Name 
,mp_asin.PRODUCT_SITE_LAUNCH_DAY AS PSLD 
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME as TEEN 
,mp_asin.BRAND_CODE AS Brand_Code 
,mp_asin.REPLENISHMENT_CODE as REPLEN_CODE 
,mp_asin.REPLENISHMENT_CATEGORY_ID AS Replen_TIER
,mp_asin.ASIN as ASIN
,MIN(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME)) as MIN_TEEN_RC
,MAX(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME)) as MAX_TEEN_RC
FROM
d_mp_asins mp_asin
WHERE 1=1
AND mp_asin.CATEGORY_CODE =('30905500') 
AND mp_asin.SUBCATEGORY_CODE =('30905560')
AND mp_asin.REGION_ID = 1
AND mp_asin.MARKETPLACE_ID = 1
AND mp_asin.GL_PRODUCT_GROUP = 309
)
where MIN_TEEN_RC <> MAX_TEEN_RC;
```

Comment: This worked great...though I miss labeled the alias just before the partition...lol...thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

> **ORA-00904** can simply be avoided by using the valid column name in
>   create or alter statement. Also for DML statements ORA-00904 can be
>   avoided by making a valid reference to the column name or the alias.

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT
mp_asin.CATEGORY_CODE AS Category_id 
,mp_asin.SUBCATEGORY_CODE AS SUBCATEGORY
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME 
,mp_asin.COLOR_NAME AS Color_Name 
,mp_asin.PRODUCT_SITE_LAUNCH_DAY AS PSLD 
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME as TEEN 
,mp_asin.BRAND_CODE AS Brand_Code 
,mp_asin.REPLENISHMENT_CODE as REPLEN_CODE 
,mp_asin.REPLENISHMENT_CATEGORY_ID AS Replen_TIER
,mp_asin.ASIN as ASIN
,MIN(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME)) as MIN_TEEN_RC
,MAX(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME)) as MAX_TEEN_RC

FROM
d_mp_asins mp_asin
) T
WHERE    
T.MIN_TEEN_RC <> T.MAX_TEEN_RC
AND T.CATEGORY_CODE =('30905500') 
AND T.SUBCATEGORY_CODE =('30905560')
AND T.REGION_ID = 1
AND T.MARKETPLACE_ID = 1
AND T.GL_PRODUCT_GROUP = 309
```

Comment: I guess in the outer query, mp_asin alias should be replaced by T like - 

AND mp_asin.CATEGORY_CODE =('30905500') 
to be replaced by AND T.CATEGORY_CODE =('30905500')

Answer (score 0):

You can not use alias in WHERE clause. You need to bring group function code to HAVING clause:

```
HAVING MIN(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME)) <> 
       MAX(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME))
```

But basically, your query idea is not good. The GROUP BY is not necessary.